# How to delete,reset or write "null" value in sql base after datetimepicker already(saved) written record?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have win Form and i use DateTimePicker for date and time info on saving depending on status.Every time when user use IDStatus "1", i want to delete record in base which he wroted before with selecting IDStatus "2" using DateTimePicker.Here is the code:

```
    private void m021BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IDStatusTextBox.Focus();
            if (IDStatusTextBox.Text == "1")
            {
                dateofstartDateTimePicker.Value = null;  
                Save();
                Refresh();
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (IDStatusTextBox.Text == "2")
            {
                dateofstartDateTimePicker.Focus();
                if (dateofstartTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    dateofstartDateTimePicker.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dateofstartDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
                }
                Save();
                Refresh();
                this.Close();
```

Comment: Explain better what is the problem. I can't understand by reading the title-summary.

Comment: well i simply have a combobox which has 2 values. So when user select first value ,datetimepicker saves current date at base.Now i want that record to be deleted next time when user select second value from combobox.

Comment: That combobox has 2 options better say 2 values, thats why i said at code
IDStatusTextBox.Text == "2" or "1".

Comment: Post the database table that you save the dates.

Comment: So basicly when user select 2nd option from combobox i am checking is there any date at the moment in base, if there is not datetimepicker write's date. If there is date already , nothing will happen, also if user select 1st option from combobox i want to delete or null that value in base which was written before by same user when he used 2nd option.

Comment: Its a simple column in table, name of that column where datetimepicker write's dates is named "dateofstart" like you can see in code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a datetimepicker value to null

I don't know how you use your base, but the simplest for me, will be to use SQL to delete your value.

You can easily do something like "DELETE (yourdate) FROM (yourtable) WHERE [UserID] = (yourUserID)

Comment: Yes i know that, but somehow i want to insert "nothing" as record.